# how to use annotate to sum up all rows and get the avg? django

Tags: python, django, sum, average

I was googling about this and there is a simplier way which uses `Cast` but then thing is I believe that's for `django 2.0` that mine is `django 1.9`

I found a post and I tried it, it doesn't really work for me though.

Let's say I have a model with `value` and `max` fields.
I want to get the sum of all `value` and `max` then divide them to get the average.  What I did just gets one row and return the avg of the row, can someone let me know what I have been doing wrong here?

```
model_calcuation = Model.objects.filter().annotate(
    sum_score=Sum('value', output_field=FloatField()),
    sum_max=Sum('max', output_field=FloatField())
).annotate(
    avg=F('sum_score') / F('sum_max')
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you are looking for [**`aggregate()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions) operation.

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

model_calcuation = Model.objects.aggregate(result=Sum(F('value')) / Sum(F('max')))
```

Comment: damn I thought I tried that and it didn't work...maybe I was reading through posts and kept trying and trying and mixed up myself.  Let me give this a try

Comment: sryz just got one more question I forgot to ask, wonder if you can also let me know here instead of me posting another post.  I want to filter out all that has the same `value, max` but I tried using `distinct()` it didn't work though.  If I put `distinct()` infront of  `aggregate()` nothing happens, if I put it after `aggregate()` I get error since `aggregate()` changed it to `dict` obj

Comment: I believe I figured out, I have to use `value('value', 'max').distinct().aggregate()`

Comment: What you mean by *filter out all that has the same value, max*?